# History manipulation interferes with iframe

Tags: javascript

I have this site which dynamically loads content via. javascript. One of the pages has an iframe on it, and for some reason, the script that is supposed to manipulate the history of the window, manipulates the iframe instead.

```
$('.section-back').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if(self.history.length == 0) {
        getPage($(this).attr('data-parent'));   
    }
    else self.history.back(); 
});
```

Someone told me to use `self`, so I tried that, but still no hope.

Do anyone know why this happens and possibly have a solution? 
Thank you very much, this has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: Could you show us the markup of a sample page, or make a short demo? And does this happen in all browsers or only some specific?

Comment: 1. What mark-up would you like me to post? :) And i don't think demo is possible. My site use a lot of the new technologies, so the site itself doesn't work in like IE.

Comment: Here is all the markup http://pastebin.com/BwYMwC5j